# Wittgenstein on algorithm decidability and Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: logic, wittgenstein

I found Internet resources a bit confusing, so I ask this question:

What are Wittgenstein's arguments on algorithm decidability and Godel's Incompleteness Theorem?

Comment: Could you, perhaps, explain a bit further how did your question come up? Can you contextualize the problem stating what you already know about it?

Comment: The body of your question should add background and context to your title question, not simply repeat it. Can you tell us anything at all you know about these two things, where exactly you are being tripped up, etc.?

Comment: What sources were you reading that were confusing?

Comment: It was totally incorrect that this question was closed for a lack of focus, at least with regarding Wittgenstein's arguments on Godel's Incompleteness Theorem. Wittgenstein's Wittgenstein's " notorious paragraph " about the Gödel Theorem is very well known.

Answer (score 2):

Wittgenstein's arguments about Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem are found in his [*Lectures on the Foundations of Mathematics*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226904261)

There have been several recent papers trying to assess Wittgenstein's comments; for example, [here](http://sammelpunkt.philo.at:8080/1674/1/ohmacht.pdf) and [here](http://www.nd.edu/~tbays/papers/wnp.pdf).

Are you finding the arguments in these sources unclear?

Comment: Because I came up with Wittgenstein's exact same reasoning independently on my own before I ever heard of him I understand it completely. I will sum up a concise paraphrase of it. **Unless an expression of language can be proved true or false it is simply not a truth bearer.**